# Setting a shared title within a common Header View amongst Views; per Active View

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

**Goal:** To use a common header View containing a shared title Text().

**Scenario:** I have multiple Views that share a common tab space *within the one container tab View* that contains a struct Header that is to be shared.

This is a (many : 1) scenario.

**Note:** I don't want to use a NavigationView because it screws up landscape mode.  A simple small header View is fine.  I just need to populate the shared Title space amongst the member Views.

I don't want to merely add duplicate headers (having exactly the same layout) for each member View.

**Several ideas:** I need the header to respond to the 'change of title' event so I can see the new title.

So I believe I could use 1) @Binder(each member View) --> @State (shared Header View) or 
 2) @Environment.

I don't know how I could fit #1 into this particular scenario. 
So I'm playing with #2: Environment Object.

**DesignPattern:** Main Header View's title set by multiple Views so the Header View is not aware of the multiple Views:

[image]

I'm not getting the EnvironmentObject paradigm to work.

Here's the codes... 
MainView:

```
import SwiftUI

// Need to finish this.

class NYTEnvironment {
    var title = "Title"
    var msg = "Mother had a feeling..."
}

class NYTSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var environment: NYTEnvironment
    init() {
        self.environment = NYTEnvironment()
    }
}

struct NYTView: View {
    var nytSettings  = NYTSettings()
     
    @State var selectionDataSegmentIndex = 0

    var bindingDataSourceSegment: Binding<Int> {
        .init(get: {
            selectionDataSegmentIndex
        }, set: {
            selectionDataSegmentIndex = $0
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        let county = 0; let state = 1; let states = 2

        VStack {
            NYTHeaderView()
            SegmentAndDataPickerVStack(spacing: 10) {
                if let segments = Source.NYT.dataSegments {
                    Picker("NYT Picker", selection: bindingDataSourceSegment) {
                        ForEach(segments.indices, id: \.self) { (index: Int) in
                            Text(segments[index])
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }
            if selectionDataSegmentIndex == county {
                NYTCountyView()
            } else if selectionDataSegmentIndex == state {
                NYTStateView()
            } else if selectionDataSegmentIndex == states {
                NYTStatesView()
            }
            Spacer()
        }.environmentObject(nytSettings)
    }

    struct TrailingItem: View {
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                print("Info")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
            })
        }
    }
}

// ====================================================================================

struct NYTHeaderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var nytSettings: NYTSettings
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            Text(nytSettings.environment.title)
        }.frame(height: Header.navigationBarHeight)
    }
}
```

Revision: I've added EnvironmentObject modifiers to the memberViews():

```
if selectionDataSegmentIndex == county {
                NYTCountyView().environmentObject(NYTSettings())
            } else if selectionDataSegmentIndex == state {
                NYTStateView().environmentObject(NYTSettings())
            } else if selectionDataSegmentIndex == states {
                NYTStatesView().environmentObject(NYTSettings())
            }
            ...
```

One of the member Views that's within the Main Container/Tab View (per above):

```
struct NYTCountyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource = NYTCountyModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var nytSettings: NYTSettings
    ...
    ...

 }.onAppear {
       nytSettings.environment.title = "Selected Counties"
                            
       if dataSource.revisedCountyElementListAndDuration == nil {
              dataSource.getData()
          }
       }
       Spacer()
       ...
}
```

Here's the compile-time error:

[image]

**Modus Operandi:** Set the title w/in header per member View upon .onAppear().

**Problem:** I'm not getting any title; just the default "Title" value.

**Question:** Am I on the right track?  
If so, what am I missing?

 or... is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem boils down to a 'Many : 1' paradigm. 
I got this revelation via taking a break and going for a walk.

So this is the proverbial 'round peg in a square hole' scenario.

What I needed was a *lightly coupled* relationship where the origin of the title value isn't required.  
Hence the use of the **Notification** paradigm.

The header view's title is the receiver and hence I used the **.onReceive** modifier:

```
struct NYTHeaderView: View {
    @State private var title: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            Text(title).onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .headerTitle)) {note in
                title = note.object as? String ?? "New York Times"
            }

        }.frame(height: Header.navigationBarHeight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what SwiftUI preferences was built to solve. The preferences are values collected and reduced from children for some distant ancestor to use. One notable example of this is how `NavigationView` gets its title - the title is set on the child, not on the `NavigationView` itself:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("I am a simple view")
        .navigationTitle("Title")
}
```

---

So, in your case you have some kind of title (simplified to `String` for brevity) that each child view might want to set. So you'd define a `TitlePreferenceKey` like so:

```
struct TitlePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: String = ""
    
    static func reduce(value: inout String, nextValue: () -> String) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Here, the `reduce` function is simply applying the last value it sees from descendants, but since you'd only ever have one child view selected it should work.

Then, to use it, you'd have something like this:

```
struct NYTView: View {
   @State var title = ""
   @State var selection = 0

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Text(title)
         Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            Text("SegmentA").tag(0)
            Text("SegmentB").tag(1)
         }

         switch selection {
         case 0: NYTCountyView()
         case 1: NYTStateView()
                   .preference(key: TitlePreferenceKey.self, value: "State view")
         default: EmptyView()
         }
      }
      .onPreferenceChange(TitlePreferenceKey.self) {
         self.title = $0
      }
   }
```

```
struct NYTCountyView: View {
   @State var selectedCounty = "..."

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           //...
       }
       .preference(key: TitlePreferenceKey.self, value: selectedCounty)
   }
}
```

So, a preference can be set by the parent of, as in the example of `NYTStateView`, or by the child with the value being dynamic, as in the example of `NYTCountyView`

Comment: The PreferenceKey approach apparently only works with the NavigationView.   I'm not using NavigationView because it interferes with portrait->landscape mode in my app.  I want a completely different View in landscape vs portrait.   Hence the simpler static View with title.  In this scenario, the Preference approach doesn't work; however the Notification paradigm does.  Saying that, I appreciate what you gave me and shall note it for a Navigation-Centric paradigm.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee... Hmm.. PreferenceKey is not only for `NavigationView`, in my example there's no `NavigationView`. PreferenceKey is a way for multiple views to communicate with their distance ancestor in a one-to-many way

Comment: I'm not getting it to work; and all my references point to NavigationView;  I'll play with it more.  I forgot the header view itself.  I didn't load the title value from the preferencekey.  Studying it.

Comment: Yah... I followed your example and I can't get it to work on my end.  Title in static view doesn't change.  However, the notification --> receiver paradigm works.

Comment: Hard to know what exactly doesn't work for you, but bear in mind that `.onPreferenceChange` has to be done on the ancestor - not on a sibling view, @FrederickC.Lee. That's not to say that notification approach isn't the right thing to do - it provides a completely decoupled design. I'm not commenting on what's the right thing for you - just that preference keys is a way to communicate/aggregate values from descendents

Comment: I need to learn the Prefence paradigm in any case.   So I'll toy with it.